# Android 6.0 HtppURLConnection Crash Error

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm using this codes in asynctask for load data from URL. I added internet permissions in manifest.xml, I haven't any errors on Android Studio but when i debugging application, going crash. Where is my fault?

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("my_url");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        jsonString = buffer.toString();
        if(connection != null) { connection.disconnect(); }
        try {
            if(reader != null) { reader.close();  }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I believe that `httpurlconnection` is deprecated.

Comment: I don't make anythink but it works.. thanks :)  @CommonsWare